# Can I use the same boost::asio::io_service for multiple listening sockets?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using Boost asio 1.48. Is it possible to re-use a single `boost::asio::io_service` instance for multiple listening sockets that are open simultaneously?

The docs say its share-safe, but I am not sure if that is already a positive answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can, and you should. And you can use that same `io_service` to handle those sockets, handle timers, handle requests you `post` to it, and so on. The whole point of an `io_service` is to act as a central dispatcher for work of all kinds.